# Re-write Excel formula to run in mySQL

Tags: mysql

In Excel, I have this formula to take a price, mark it up by 1.5% and then round that up to the next $10:

```
=ROUNDUP(SUM(A2*1.015),-1)
```

I would like to do the same thing in MySQL, if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT CEIL(150.37*1.015);
```

And your final query must looks like this:

```
SELECT CEIL(PRICEFIELD*1.015) AS Price FROM YourTable;
```